# How to 'Block Download' in an API created Share Link

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using the API (HTTP Request through PowerAutomate) to create a share link for a file that is being submitted via a Form.

This share link will be displaying a PDF and needs to have certain permissions, such as View by everyone + Block Download.

I can do this via the GUI fine, but when using the API I am unsuccessful in blocking the download.

I am using a POST to URI- _api/web/GetFileByUrl(@v)/ListItemAllFields/ShareLink?@v='@{outputs('Compose_2')}'

Outputs of Compose_2 is the Relative path of the file submitted via the form.

The body of the request is-

[image: bodyofAPIrequest]

The request is hitting the API and I am getting a response. The link created is one that anyone can view, which is perfect, but I still cannot get "Block Download" to work. Everywhere I have read, says role 7 should block the download. Can anyone point me in the direction of some documentation that would help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring below settings

[image]

Then you can use following request data:

```
    {
  "request": {
    "createLink": true,
    "settings": {
      "allowAnonymousAccess": true,
      "linkKind": 6,
      "expiration": null,
      "role": 7,
      "restrictShareMembership": false,
      "updatePassword": false,
      "password": null,
      "scope": 0
    }
  }
}
```

As this is API is not properly documented anywhere by Microsoft, I would always use [Fiddler Classic](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic) to where you can do operation in SharePoint and use Fiddler to check what request data is being sent by SharePoint.

Below are available options for different property to be passed with request data. As it's enum, input should be provided in number and it will start with 0,1, and so on.

**linkKind**

[image]

**role**

[image]

**scope**

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have been away! Thankyou so much for answering though! Works perfect!

Comment: Please mark this answer if it works for so that it can be helpful to other person